# Python Create data frame from existing data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am given the following data frame with columns "total_bill," "tip," "sex," "smoker," "day," "time," and "size." Row values for "smoker" can be "Yes" or "No". Row values for "time" can be "Lunch" or "Dinner".

**Given data frame:**

```
total_bill tip sex smoker day time size
0 16.99 1.01 Female No Sunday Dinner 2
1 10.34 1.66 Male No Sunday Dinner 3
2 21.01 3.50 Male No Sunday Dinner 3
3 23.68 3.31 Male No Sunday Dinner 2
4 24.59 3.61 Female No Sunday Dinner 4
```

I need to create the following:

1. Data frame for size (number) of dinners and lunches
2. Data frame for the amount of smokers by time (Lunch: Amount of smokers, Dinner: Amount of smokers)
3. Combine the two data frames above

**Expected output:** "?" represents numerical value derived

|  | Records | Smokers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lunch | ? | ? |
| Dinner | ? | ? |

**My code:**

```
# Number of Time (Lunch/Dinner) records
df1 = tips_df.groupby('time')['size'].sum()

def myfunction(x):
    if x == 'Yes':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

#Number of Smoker records by Time (Lunch/Dinner)
mydata['Smoker_numerical'] = tips_df['smoker'].apply(lambda x: myfunction(x))
mydata = mydata.astype({'Smoker_numerical': 'int32'})
mydata2 = mydata.groupby('time')['Smoker_numerical'].sum()

result = concat([df1, mydata2], axis=1)
result
```

My code to determine the amount of smokers by time is outputting the following error message.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/wv/42dn23fd1cb0czpvqdnb6zw00000gn/T/ipykernel_13833/1039123812.py in <module>
      8 
      9 mydata['Smoker_numerical'] = tips_df['smoker'].apply(lambda x: myfunction(x))
---> 10 mydata = mydata.astype({'Smoker_numerical': 'int32'})
     11 mydata2 = mydata.groupby('time')['Smoker_numerical'].sum()
     12 

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5876             if self.ndim == 1:  # i.e. Series
   5877                 if len(dtype) > 1 or self.name not in dtype:
-> 5878                     raise KeyError(
   5879                         "Only the Series name can be used for "
   5880                         "the key in Series dtype mappings."

KeyError: 'Only the Series name can be used for the key in Series dtype mappings.'
```

Is there any way to fix this, or another way to determine the amount of smokers by time? Thanks.

Comment: where is ``mydata`` defined? And where exactly error appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `agg`:

```
result = df.assign(smoker=df['smoker'] == 'Yes').groupby('time', as_index=False) \
           .agg(Records=('size', 'sum'), Smokers=('smoker', 'sum'))
print(result)

# Output
     time  Records  Smokers
0  Dinner       14        0
```

**Update**

> How do I get the smokers by time?

```
>>> df.groupby('smoker', as_index=False)['time'].count() 
  smoker  time
0     No     5
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! For individual data frames, I was able to get the time by size, but how do I get the smokers by time? I tried `tips_df.groupby('smoker')['time'].sum()`, but that does not work for me.

Comment: You can use `count` instead of `sum`: `df.groupby('smoker')['time'].count()`. I updated my answer, can you check it?

Comment: When I tried using this `df.groupby('smoker')['time'].count()`, I got a different output (Smokers 93 151) than the `result` command (Smokers 23 70). Do you know what might be the reason for this difference?

Comment: `df.groupby('smoker', as_index=False)['time'].count()` also outputs `Smokers 93 151` while the result command outputs `Smokers 23 70`. Do you know what might be the reason for this difference?

Comment: You have only 2370 smokers (Yes). The column should me named `is_smoker?` 93151 is the number of records (smoker or not)

Comment: I mean that `df.groupby('smoker', as_index=False)['time'].count()` outputs `Smokers Yes Time 93, Smoker No Time 151` while the result command outputs `Smoker Lunch 23, Smoker Dinner 70`.  I want to get the second column from the result command so that I get `Smoker Lunch 23, Smoker Dinner 70`.

Comment: I don't understand. You want two different things. You can't obtain 23 and 70 if you group by `smoker` You have to group by `time` if you want to get a such result: `df.assign(smoker=df['smoker'] == 'Yes').groupby('time', as_index=False)['smoker'].sum()`

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. I appreciate it. I have another unrelated question though. Is there a way to calculate the percentage of smokers during lunch and dinner respectively? I tried using `tips_df['percent_smoker'] = tips_df['Smokers'] / tips_df['Records'] * 100`, but it does not work.

Comment: You want the percentage from `result` or `tips_df`? Because in `tips_df`, you have not `Smokers` and `Records` columns

Comment: Percentage from result. I modified it so that it calculates the percentage from result now. Thank you again!

Comment: Where is the problem with `result['Smokers'] / result['Records'] * 100`?